# Unable to update state in react Context API - returns null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mern

I'm unable to correctly implement state from the Context API Hook. I use it in 2 different files - it works perfectly in one of them (state changes), and in the other one it returns 'null'

Here's the context file with state:

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const SearchContext = createContext();

export function SearchProvider({ children }) {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("SPY")
    return (
        <SearchContext.Provider value={{ search, setSearch }}>{children}</SearchContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default SearchContext;
```

And this is the file it's not working in:

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import SearchContext from '../searchContext';


const StockSearchBar = () => {
   
  function handleButtonEvents(e) {
        handleClick();
    setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(), 3000);
    }

  const { search, setSearch } = useContext(SearchContext);


  const handleSearch = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.value !== ``) {
    setSearch(e.target.value.toUpperCase())
    }
  };


  const handleClick = (e) => {

    if (setSearch !== '') {

      const options = 
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({search}), // I suspect the problem is here, because it's supposed to send a word to mongodb backend - but it's receiving 'null' in the database
      };
  
      const response = fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/search`, options);
    };
  }

  return (
      
      <>
    <div className="searchBar">
      <label>Look for Stocks or Cryptos: </label>
      <input  type='text' onChange={handleSearch} onKeyPress={(ev) => {
        if (ev.key === "Enter") {
          handleButtonEvents();
    }
  }
}
      placeholder={search} required/>
      <Button variant="success" type="submit" onClick={handleButtonEvents}>Search</Button>
    </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default StockSearchBar;
```

in short to describe what this is doing: it's a searchbar that's supposed to change state based on what user types in and send a post request to retrieve information from backend

I could just throw everything into one file, but this wouldnt be considered " good " practice......

If instead of the context API, I try useState - it will work fine.. not sure what the problem is

Should I include the other file it's working in ?
Please let me know if this is understandable - and thank you in advance for taking time to figure out the problem.

EDIT:

index.js file with all the components

```
<>
 <SearchProvider>  
  <Router>   
  <Navbar /> 
    <Routes>

      <Route exact path="/" element={
          <>
                <LineChart />
                <App />
                <StockSearchBar />
                <HowTo />
                <SpecialChars />
          </>
      } />

      <Route exact path="/crypto" element={
          <>
                <Crypto />

          </>
      } />

    </Routes>

  
  </Router>
  </SearchProvider>
</>
```

Comment: Have you imported your provider somewhere and wrapped the rest of your code in it?

Comment: Is the component wrapped in the `SearchProvider`?

Comment: hey @SlavaKnyazev  sorry I was outside, and yes the whole app is wrapped in a SearchProvider.

Comment: yes @Andy I updated the code to include index.js

Comment: it seems like the searchbar sends nothing